# How to view VBA properties of excel filter that was created via the built in filter button?

Tags: excel, vba

When you use the 'Filter' button in excel, surely there are VBA properties behind that specific filter that are viewable somehow (like creator, filtermode, range, etc as laid out by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.autofilter). I know you can write your own autofilter with VBA, but I want to create a filter using the built in functionality on the home tab, and then view the VBA properties of that specific filter. How can I do this?

I've looked it up in a bunch of different search terms, but I haven't found anything that can tell me how to do what I'm asking. I've checked out the developer and inquire tabs in excel, but I didn't see what I'm looking for in either.

Edit: I was able to use the code from #17 in https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-autofilter/#17-Excel-VBA-Get-AutoFiltered-Range to find what I was looking for.

`MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("[Sheet name]").AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to do it, but here is a simple work around.  Add a new filter to the existing filter.  Then, use the macro recorder to record changing the filter back to what it was originally.  (In other words, record removing the addition to the filter.)  The macro recorder will write out all parameters of the filter, and since you just removed the parameter that isn't what you care about, it will write out all the parameters of the filter still active.  And there you have it: all the settings of the filter you care about, written in VBA code.